# Document cannot be printed - no pages were selected

Tags: printing

I'm using TexnixCenter using Latex->PDF. I have never had any problems with printing, but recently this message starts turning up... (Document cannot be printed - no pages were selected)

I can still print other PDF documents, so the problem seems to be in my file. I just cannot seem to find it …

Comment: Well, a good starting point would be to post the document code here (if it's not too long), so we can have something to work with. :D

Comment: I know, but it's an entire book with many included files. I was hoping someone else had experienced a similar problem :)

Comment: By printing, do you mean physically printing pages or typesetting a PDF?

Comment: I mean physically printing the finished PDF. At the moment I'm trying to print it to another PDF, but it doesn't work...

Comment: What program do you use to view PDFs? The PDF might be corrupted. In that case, you can try moving it to another folder, typesetting it again in Latex and then try printing.

Comment: Just put "Document cannot be printed - no pages were selected" into a search engine. You'll find a lot of adobe acrobat related answers. Or use an opensource PDF reader.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.

Try to open the pdf file using any browser say Google Chrome or Firefox using path like file://C:/Documents/my-pdf-file.pdf

Then try to print.

The issue is with signatures or security in pdf document, which restrict PDF viewer to print the document.